# webapp start with log4j debug before load log4j.properties

Tags: java, servlets, logging, struts2, log4j

I use log4j since 2010. Great tool.
In a new software I imported the same configuration and libs, but at deploy the app start with logging level DEBUG (but I haven't set the debug level).
**It logs all struts2 and hibernate configuration (about 500 lines)!**
After hibernate and struts2 start-up, finally, the software call the init method and sets the loggin level at ERROR. (and all works good)

*I don't like this behaviour: I'd like to have all log immediately at ERROR level.
In all my other softwares it works fine.*

---

I was used to this standard configuration:
I load the log4j.properties in a servlet in the init method, in the web.xml I use this (I tried also with 0 and -1):

```
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

Init method of the servlet

```
@Override
    public void init() {
       PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4j_address);
}
```

Here is the log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootCategory=error, stdout
log4j.logger.org=error
log4j.logger.com=error
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%7p %d{DATE} %-20F:%3L - %m%n
```

Comment: so where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that both in develop and production I have too much row of log at every startup.

Comment: @Balda Could the problem be that you are seeing too many log statements?

Comment: yes, too many at the start up. And I dont' understand why. In all my other software the same configuration works fine.

Comment: what server are you deploying on (tomcat, websphere, jboss, ...)? And is it the same as the other applications that do work?

Comment: You don't need to load the configuration manually; put a log4j.properties (or XML) at the root of the classpath, and it will be picked up immediately, and everything can be configured in one place.

Comment: I tried without servlet, but it doesn't work. I use the basic configuration like descript here  (Default Initialization under Tomcat)http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html